# MySQL SUM of column duplicating based on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables

subtitles_request

```
movie_id | user_id | sent
2002     |    1    |   1
2002     |    2    |   1
2002     |    3    |   1
2002     |    4    |   1
2002     |    5    |   1
2002     |    6    |   1
2002     |    7    |   1
2002     |    8    |   1
```

email_schedule

```
movie_id | schedule_id
2002     |  1
2002     |  2
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT SUM(a.sent) as sent FROM subtitles_request a
JOIN email_schedule c on c.movie_id=a.movie_id
```

The issue is this part of the query `SUM(a.sent) as sent`. `sent` is being duplicated because their are two rows on email_schedule that are joined.  So instead of `8` i get `16`.

How do i solve, so `sent` column doesn't get doubled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add `DISTINCT movie_id` in subquery for `email_schedule`, because there are two row in the `email_schedule` table which is `movie_id = 2002`, the will relation with `subtitles_request` table, which `movie_id = 2002`

so you will get `2*8 = 16` data row.

```
CREATE TABLE subtitles_request(
    movie_id INT,
    user_id INT,
  sent INT
);


INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,2 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,3 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,4 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,5 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,6 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,7 ,1);
INSERT INTO subtitles_request VALUES (2002,8 ,1);
CREATE TABLE email_schedule
(
    movie_id INT,
    schedule_id INT
);

INSERT INTO email_schedule VALUES (2002,  1);
INSERT INTO email_schedule VALUES (2002,  2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(a.sent) as sent 
FROM subtitles_request a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT movie_id  FROM email_schedule) c on c.movie_id=a.movie_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10327/1/0)**:

```
| sent |
|------|
|    8 |
```